# Phalconphp Blank webtools page

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm using Linux, and created phalcon project via terminal with the command : 
`phalcon project phalconBlog --enable-webtools`

but when I try to open localhost/phalconBlog/webtools.php in the web browser, I see just a blank, empty page whereas I have to see a page like this:

[image: webtools.php]

The project is in my desktop. And I could not find the solution.

My webtools.php file:

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Web\Tools;

require 'webtools.config.php';

require PTOOLSPATH . '/scripts/Phalcon/Web/Tools.php';

Tools::main(PTOOLSPATH, PTOOLS_IP);
```

My webtools.config.php file:

```
<?php

define('PTOOLS_IP', '192.168.');

define('PTOOLSPATH', '/home/johnylesh/phalconBlog/app/library/vendor/phalcon/devtools');
```

Note:in my project folder, there is no such a folder named app/library.

Comment: Why is there only half an ip? Whats your error logs say?

Comment: In the comment part of the ip, it says: "phalcon Developers Tools can only be used in local machines, however you can set this to allow certain IP address. For example:
 *   192.168.0.1 or SUBNET 192., 10.0.2., 86.84.124."     And I did not get any error, just a blank empty page.